# Consume messages from Kafka topic partition from an offset / from a date when auto commit set to true

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, kafka-consumer-api, alpakka

Dependency used **Alpakka Kafka 3.0**

We have below consumer settings.

**enable.auto.commit = true**

**auto.offset.reset = earliest**

If We have enable.auto.commit = true then is it possible to consume messages from Kafka topic partition from a particular offset / from a date?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assign` method instead of `subscribe` method

```
 public void sample() {
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
        TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition("some-topic", 0);
        consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition));
        consumer.seek(partition, 0);
        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, it is not necessary to specify the consumer group when you are using the assign method instead of subscribe method, in
the Consumer properties, and hence probably will ignore those parameters (enable.auto.commit,auto.offset.reset). Use the assign method and seek only for debugging or testing purposes.

There is also another method called offsetsForTimes to get the desired offset to seek.

Comment: In Alpakka Kafka, you should be able to get similar results with the `plainExternalSource` in Alpakka's `Consumer`.

Comment: Consumer offsets are stored in Kafka only. There is no other data source used for storing an offset.
Is it possible to retrieve records from an offset or particular time stamp using the plainExternalSource API?

Comment: @AkshayJain, you would use the `MetadataClient` (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer-metadata.html), specifically its `.getCommittedOffsets` method to retrieve the committed offsets.  Then based on the committed offsets (e.g. subtract 2000 from the last committed offsets in each partition), you would construct a `Subscription` to pass to the `plainExternalSource`.

Comment: In Alpakka Kafka, after constructing a `KafkaConsumerActor`, you can get the offset for a particular time by using the ask pattern with a `GetOffsetsForTimes` message.

Comment: @LeviRamsey , 

Can we use subscription API's ?

For Partition Assignment with Offset we have Subscriptions.assignmentWithOffset API


and For Partition Assignment with Timestamp we have Subscriptions.assignmentOffsetsForTimes API.

 Subscription API documentation 
[link](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/subscription.html)

Comment: Yeah, the Subscription API is what you'd use to tell the `plainExternalSource` what offset to start from.  For getting a raw offset, you would use the `MetadataClient` and you shouldn't have to use anything special to get offsets for times.

Comment: For the Subscriptions API, we need to pass TopicPartition. Is it possible to fetch the records from a particular timestamp without specifying partitions?